# SQL Table Update

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables as follows and I need to update WorksOperation Table with data from WorksTracking

WorksTracking Table.

```
ID  WorksID  WorksOperationID  DateTime                 SubOperationID  EmployeeID 
1   2182     5363              2012-11-26 12:30:00.000  3               96
2   6866     9856              2012-11-26 10:26:00.000  3               100
3   2182     5363              2012-11-26 16:13:00.000  4               96
4   6866     9856              2012-11-26 13:42:00.000  4               100
6   2182     5363              2012-11-26 06:30:00.000  3               96
7   2182     5363              2012-11-26 12:30:00.000  4               96
```

The SubOperationID = 3 = Start 4 = End

THIS IS WHAT I NEED

WorksOperation Table.

```
ID  WorksID  WorksOperationID  StartTime                EndTime                SubOpID  EmpID 
1   2182     5363              2012-11-26 12:30:00.000  2012-11-26 16:13:00.000  4       96
2   6866     9856              2012-11-26 10:26:00.000  2012-11-26 13:42:00.000  4       100
3   2182     5363              2012-11-26 06:30:00.000  2012-11-26 12:30:00.000  4       96
```

Comment: Please specify the RDBMS that you are targeting by adding the appropriate tag (Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL, etc.). There may be answers that take advantage of language or product features that are not universally supported. Also, by tagging it with a specific RDBMS, your question may receive attention from people better suited to answer it

Answer (score 0):

This will work on SQL Server (2005 and newer), but if that is not your RDBMS, it can easily be adapted:

```
    ;WITH ALLSTARTS AS 
( 
    SELECT * FROM WorksTracking WHERE SubOperationID = 3
)
--INSERT INTO WorksOperation 
SELECT  s.WorksID ,
        s.WorksOperationID ,
        s.DateTime AS StartTime,
        e.DateTime AS EndTime,
        e.SubOperationID AS SubOpID,
        e.EmployeeID FROM ALLSTARTS s 
INNER JOIN dbo.WorksTracking e ON e.SubOperationID = 4 
AND e.DateTime = (SELECT MIN(e.DateTime) FROM WorksTracking e WHERE s.WorksID = e.WorksID AND s.WorksOperationID = e.WorksOperationID AND e.DateTime>s.DateTime)
```

[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/74da2/4)

Comment: HI When I run the query the worksoperation table does not update could you please help as when I run thequery the result are correct but the update is not tacking effect

Comment: The INSERT row is put under comments for example of result set, just remove comments from beginning of that line. However, please note that I have assumed that there are now rows in WorksOperation and this query is inserting new rows. If you actually already have rows and just need some columns updated, please tell so because, query needs to be rewritten a bit.

Comment: I need to post you my results if that ok as something does not appear right as it is putting start & end time in the future in.

Comment: sorry I forgot to say if thats ok

Comment: You can use sqlfiddle.com to create schema and data and easily share with others to check out.

Comment: Hi I figured out the previous issue but now when I run the query I get the following error                                          Msg 213, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Insert Error: Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.

Comment: In my example I've created ID column on WorksOperation table as IDENTITY(1,1) - it's autoincrement so it's omitted from SELECT statement. If this is not the case in your situation, I would suggest altering table to add IDENTITY to this column. Calucalating your own values for ID could complicate things a bit.

Comment: However it's not impossible - if you can not alter columns Identity property - check this sql fiddle for example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0a17e/1

Comment: If you look at the sqlfiddle.com schema they are the columns I have but the 3 columns I have added have null values so far

Comment: if you look at the results in http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d53d7/1 you will see that employee 96 is also getting the times for employee 128 so it is duplicating times